# Error: bundling failed: ambiguous resolution. Cannot solve by clear cache

Tags: react-native

[image]

I clone this project from my friend's Github, then npm install and run-ios. This error appears only in my device, not in my friend's device.

I try many ways to fix it: npm/yarn reset cache, delete node_modules and re-install, reset vscode as well as my laptop,... but all of them do not work.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

remove ios/build folder, then retry